# How do you pronounce this word in Onkelos

Tags: grammar-dikduk

This word in Onkelos bereshis 41:50.   [image]

Is the word pronounced “di y’lidat,” with the second letter of the word taking the sh’va na sound, or is the second letter of the word silent, with the word being pronounced “dilidat.”

Comment: Most versions I checked (including mechon mamre’s) don’t  have a sheva marking on the yod. So it seems clear the pronunciation is dilidat (or dileidat). https://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/u/up0110.htm

Comment: How though would the word be pronounced as it looks in the picture, which was taken of the Artscroll Chumash.

Comment: I was told by a Rav that the pronunciation of Onkelos isn't important. The Oz V'hadar Mikraos Gedolos has a pretty thorough commentary on these matters if you are interested.

Comment: Ask a Yemenite. Or listen to a recording of it being read. Then you'll know

Comment: We have [דִילֵידַת](http://cal.huc.edu/get_a_chapter.php?file=51001&sub=41&cset=H) in the Bar Ilan critical text.